# Android add music form Uri

Tags: android, uri

How I can add in my app music form my website uri

this is my code but is doesn't work

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("alshbab90.softsmedia.com/sq4.mp3");
imageButtonSound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
imageButtonSound1.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

add in the `prepareAsync()` method to your media player since you plan to get the sound from the internet, this will then require the use of a `OnPreparedListener()` to be implemented and within the listener you can start your media player there.

```
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url); // url of stream goes here
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); 
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {         
                        mp.start();
                 }
     });
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? What changes have you made to your code?